# TypeScript - One-line conditional (":" expected, expression expected)

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Converting an Express JS server to TS, and previously functioning JS conditionals are now throwing weird errors.

Example: `if (req!.body?.userObj) req.session!.userObj = req.body!.userObj`

Running with `ts-node` works fine and there are no issues. But running `tsc` to compile throws these errors:

```
error TS1109: Expression expected.  

55     if (req!.body?.userObj) req.session!.userObj = req.body!.userObj 
                     ~

middleware/payloadHandle.ts:55:27 - 
error TS1005: ':' expected.

55     if (req!.body?.userObj) req.session!.userObj = req.body!.userObj
```

Comment: What version of `tsc` are you using? The `?.` operator was added in TypeScript 3.7.

Comment: @Dai That was it... Different computer, working on 3.6

Comment: Why you don't try to make it something like this: `if (req.body.userObj)  req.session.userObj = req.body.userObj;` without `?` and `!`.  Beacuse if I'm not wrong, the `?` is an optional and to use this optional, you can make it something like this in your interfaces for an example: `interface myInterface { body?: string }`

Answer (score 0):

You make sure that TS compiler is updated: `npm i typescript@latest`.